# Email intent closes application

Tags: android, email, android-intent, gmail, launchmode

I am facing a weird behavior in my app. I have an email chooser so the user can pick the mail client he wants to send an email.

In debug mode when I picked an email client (e.g. gmail), and press back everything works fine and I am navigated to the `Activity` that launched the email client.

But when I run the app it in release application closes when the chooser dialog appears and the final application that I was running before my app is shown in the background (e.g. Facebook).

I have tried to set all kind of launchmodes for the launching activity. The two that behave as desired, at least in debug mode, are `standard` and `singletop`.

Has anyone any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace

Comment: get the error log

Comment: There is no error log. App doesn't crash. It simply closes. As I said this happens only in release mode so I can't get any stack trace.

Comment: it shouldn't be related to `launchMode`. Are you using proguard? Maybe something goes wrong in the release build. See the logcat if you have any errors.

Comment: Yes I am using proguard. I will disable it to see what will happen. Thx.

Comment: Disabling proguard didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` I saw that I had an unhandled exception in a`CirclePageIndicator`, which I was using in my activity, that was giving an `System.MethodAccessException`. This [answer](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281748/viewpagerindicator-circlepageindicator-crash-in-onsaveinstancestate/) gave me the solution I needed. Everything works flawlessly now.

Comment: You can accept this answer and that will remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: It's my own answer and I can accept it two days after I answered it. So tomorrow it will be off the list :).